# Typescript generic used in React component props requires arguments error

Tags: typescript, generics

The following code generates the error shown in the image. I can't work out what to do to appease it.

I tried changing the final line to

```
}: TableHeaderProps<T>) {}
```

but to no avail.

```
export type TableHeaderProps<T extends object> = TestableComponent & {
  title?: string;
  filters?: FilterDefinition[];
  data?: T[], 
  onFiltersUpdated?: OnFiltersUpdatedCallback;
};

export function TableHeader({
  title,
  filters,
  data,
  onFiltersUpdated,
  'data-test-id': dataTestId = 'table-header',
}: TableHeaderProps) {}
```

[image: editor error]

Comment: `TableHeaderProps` is a generic, it has the `<T>` in its type definition, so you _must_ pass a type to it when you utilize it, i.e. `TableHeaderProps<MyObjectType>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the `T` to the `TableHeaderProps`. Another issue is that your `TableHeader` is not generic. You can fix it as follows:

```
export type TableHeaderProps<T extends object> = {
  data?: T[], 
  // ...
};

export function TableHeader<T extends object>({
   ...props
}: TableHeaderProps<T>) {}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwCGAjANhAwgewLZmwDsJDgoBeKAbwF8BYAKFEigDEBLNYCAJwBEIAM3aF2wdkQrV6TcNADyhDl17wAqmAAmSbpsxI0aFEgDGAaykAKAJQUAfFACuhM4WwB3Qo0YQAHgR4yZmgYVAwACQgkTV4ABR5sMHgAHhgoP25CTXgobBQAKwgTYAdKOEQwrDwCYlIoADJqRigocWAMAH4ALihEHhEAcwBuZqhhFR54brZObn4hETEJQgBtAF0RhhbtZGmYdYAaKFGiZTn1LR0ITWnFM9UNHev9Q2NzTZpNn39sQLHnYrLWCVSLRXipdK+TLZXIFIolSxUUZtDAHUbjc5orZQHZILEtU6zB6XXRYmg9ULoCCgmI8eKJFIwOy2WhAA)